# the command apt-get upgrade fails in puppet

Tags: puppet, apt

I'm running a puppet master and I need to execute these commands on my puppet agent.

## Lock kernel from updating

```
for i in $(dpkg -l "*$(uname -r)*" | grep kernel | awk '{print $2}'); do echo $i hold | dpkg --set-selections; done
```

## Update

```
apt-get update -y
```

## Upgrade

```
apt-get upgrade -y
```

`apt-get update -y` runs smoothly, but the other two aren't.

Can you give the correct Puppet syntax for this?

Comment: These kinds of non-precise commands (lock any kernel modules found, upgrade any packages found) are not really intrinsic to any CM/Orchestration/Automation software because they are considered far from best practices. Also, the kernel would not update anyway on the Debian families (you are using `apt`) unless you specified a `dist-upgrade` to `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec {'lock kernel from updating':
 command => "bash -c 'for i in $(dpkg -l "uname -r" | grep kernel | awk '{print \$2}'); do echo \$i hold | dpkg --set-selections; done'",
}

exec{'update':
  command => 'apt-get update -y',
}


exec{'upgrade':
  command => 'apt-get upgrade -y',
}
```

Comment: It's redundant to both specify `provider => shell` and run the shell command via `bash -c`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: removed it!